# Django why I can't access objects of another model via foreignkey?

Tags: python, django

I have two model Doctor and UserProfile. I want to access UserProfile model objects via foreignkey. here his my code:

**models.py**

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
      docter_id_num = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=100)
      doctor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
      slug =  models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True,blank=True,null=True) 

class UserProfile(models.Model):
      acess_doctor_model = models.ForeignKey('hospital.Doctor', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True,related_name="acess_doctor_model") 
      ....my others model fields
```

Now I need to access UserProfile model from my views fuction. here is my **views.py**

```
def EditDoctor(request,slug=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Doctor,slug=slug)
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(acess_doctor_model=obj)
    print(user_profile)
```

here is my perint result for user_profile :

```
<QuerySet [<UserProfile: None>]>
```

here is my print result for obj:

```
Doctor_id: DCKMC3G0-----Doctor Name: HARTHO
```

Why I **can't get access userprofile** model via this queryset:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(acess_doctor_model=obj)
```

**update1 question**

my str method of userprofile:

```
def __str__(self):
          return str(self.user)
```

I want to thanks Iain Shelvington. After remove str method my queryset working.

Comment: Can you share the `__str__` method of the `UserProfile` model? You are getting a result, is your issue just that None is being returned in the string representation of the UserProfile?

Comment: Iain Shelvington Thanks. After remove str method my queryset working.  I will be glad if you can little bit explain why it was not working for `__str__`???

Comment: It __was__ working, your `user_profile` queryset contained one `UserProfile`, the issue you had was the `__str__` sometimes returning the string "None" which you may have misinterpreted as no object being returned